# Javascript Hide Jquery Form

Tags: javascript, forms, append, comments

I have a js and html form that submits through php. Once submitted, the email is sent and php returns a success message that is appended to the bottom of the form using jquery.

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'process.php',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(returnedData) {
            $('#commentForm').append(returnedData);
        }
    });
    return false;
},
```

Instead, I want the js to remove and reset (hide and clear) the comment form but still append the returned data to the same location as #commentForm

Comment: Nothing successful. Thank you for any advice

Comment: Why are you going to downvote my question? There is nothing wrong with the question. It is succinct and clear, in fact

Comment: There actually is. We don't see that you put any effort into resolving this yourself.

Comment: I thought this is a question and answer site. I provide a question, it is your choice whether to answer. Thank you for your help

Comment: You, apparently, didn't read local "how to ask" document. [Here it is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) for your convenience.

Comment: Thank you I have read that before. This question meets all criteria: I have researched the issue and tried various approaches. However, there is only one answer and I have yet to find it. Easy for some, difficult for others. Thank you again

Comment: Yes, but why you failed to mention this? "Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!"

These rules are written with sweat, tears and blood. Please, do follow them in future :)

Comment: And yet this problem was solved without the need for any of this conversation thank you again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) function does that.

```
  $('#commentForm').remove();
```

Comment: .remove(); works but seems to be conflicting with .append(). How can I get the returnedData appended but remove the form?

Comment: `$('#commentForm').html('').append(returnedData);` this?

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I mean. The only problem is that the form has to wait while the php is accessed before it is removed. I am going to give you the answer but if you have any ideas of how to remove the commentForm on click rather than on success I would appreciate it. Thank you for your help

Comment: `submitHandler: function(form) { $('#commentForm').html('');`

Comment: Thank you glad to have genuine help here

Answer (score 1):

based on what @GRIGORE-TURBODISEL sayd, but with better animation you can do this

```
$('#commentForm').slideUp(1000, function(){
    $(this).html(returnedData).show('fast');
});
```

first it hides the form in 1 second, when finished emptys the html, puts in returnedData and shows it again